# How can I format the filter box in a shiny DataTables table?

Tags: r, shiny, datatables, r-markdown

In my shiny app, I would like to let my users filter an interactive datatable from the `DT` package. The `filter` option creates a very nice interactive filter tool, but the values look ugly because they're not rounded. I can use `DT::formatRound` to round the numbers in the table, but I can't figure out how to format the numbers in the filter window.

```
iris[,4:5] %>%
    mutate(x = runif(150)) %>%
    DT::datatable(filter='top') %>%
    DT::formatRound(3)
```

[image]

Comment: What's the reason against rounding before the `datatable` command? Like `iris[,4:5] |> mutate(x = round(runif(150),digits = 2)) |> DT::datatable(filter = 'top')`?

Comment: @king_of_limes That seems to work and is the quick-fix I ended up using. It's not ideal as it modifies the data in the table itself (a problem when combined with download buttons) and it seems strange that  there's no way to use `DT`'s own formatting functions with it's filter mode.